# CSS background style issue for star rating JavaScript

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to style a 5 star rating script and not coming up with anything.  The problem is that the color behind the 5 transparent stars remains white, no matter what I change.

I've tried inline `background-color:black` as well as changing `bgcolor` for the table references.  Nothing seems to be working.

[The sample is available here](http://bubba.org/rate/test.html)

The white section behind the stars is the one that I'd like to make transparent so that it picks up the color of the TD cell (`#D3DCE3`).

[The supplied CSS is here](http://bubba.org/rate/jquery/jRating.jquery.css)

I've tried changing background color for each of these elements in the CSS to black and it does not appear to impact the color of the background of the stars.

Any recommended changes would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: the white background is on the stars.png not in css

Answer (score 2):

The background of the stars is part of the image. Here is one of your stars in a blockquote so you can see the white background:

> [image: Star]

You'll need to change the image in order to change the background - CSS can't modify image colours.

Comment: This is right, i just went to the image URL and changed the background to red, and its the picture causing the issue

Comment: Thanks. I was under the assumption that the images were transparent

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't change the background color is because the white is part of the image.
Even though it's a png, the background is still white. Try a png with a transparent background.